# .htaccess redirect rules to www and htpps but to exclude subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, subdomain

After reading all relevant answers here regarding .htaccess and redirects, and some experimentation with .htaccess rewrite conditions and rules my problem persists.

I managed to force www and https for my Magento site. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

After creating the subdomain `test.example.com` and a test environment at `public_html/test/` I want to exclude it from the above rules since the subdomain will neither have a www of a https.

I tried to put this exception in the rules above but with no success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com$
```

For example, when I type  `http://test.example.com/admin/` to enter the Magento admin, it redirects me to `https://www.example.com/admin/` Do I have to also edit the `public_html/test/.htaccess file` ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is happening because of your Rules, the 2nd rule checks if the host value doesn't start with **www** the redirect the host to **www.example.com** this rule also redirects any non-www http host to the main domain with www.

To fix this, you can use a single rule to redirect http to https:www excluding the subdomain

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The above rules will work fine and exclude subdomain from https and www. But I had to rename the admin name of my test site to http://test.example.com/testadmin/ so it do not redirect to https://www.example.com/admin/. But when I try to login to my test admin, it loads the production admin panel again.